# The plurality of the word after how many

Tags: grammar, plural-forms

I think that the sentence:

> How many telephones do you have?

is incorrect.

I don't have a reason, but I feel like it should be

> How many telephone do you have?

instead.

Any one care to shed some light? Thanks.

Comment: That is super quick and clarifying, thank you so much!

Comment: Wait a few minutes before accepting an answer, as it may stop drawing attention from other answerers with better answers. But, you're welcome!

Comment: Alright.  I am new to this website. :)

Comment: No worries, people will help you get to know this network. By the way, when replying to others' comments, use and at symbol (@) and the persons name, like the one at the beginning of this comment (@jxhyc).

Comment: @Pyraminx    like Facebook, lol

Comment: Check [Unit 8 - Lesson 36 - Countable Nouns vs Uncountable Nouns How much? vs. How many?](http://www.learn-english-online.org/Lesson36/Lesson36.htm) and [how much vegetables or how many vegetables?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182954/how-much-vegetables-or-how-many-vegetables) which should be helpful. It is about *how many* {countable noun} which will be plural vs.*how much* {uncountable noun} which will be singular. I would write an explanation but you already accepted a correct answer...

Comment: @Pyraminx Seriously, 28 min.?

Comment: @user3169 Why not?

Comment: @Pyraminx Read [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) for a good explanation.

Comment: @user3169 Good to know! Thank you again, I certainly will keep In mind not to rush next time. It is interesting to see how some small details like the accept time would potentially determine the success or failure of a website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many telephone do you have?

This sentence is incorrect because it is like saying this:

> I have some telephone.

This would mean that you have a part of a telephone, rather than some whole telephones. Usually, no one would have a part of a telephone, unless half of one breaks and gets lost.

On the other hand,

> How many telephones do you have?

is correct because it is equal to saying this:

> I have some telephones.

This means that you have multiple telephones, not a part of one.

If you wanted to ask someone how big of a part of a telephone someone has (which is the implication of the sentence you feel is correct), you would actually replace the 'many' with 'much.'

> How much telephone do you have?

would be a very unlikely sentence in which you are asking about parts of telephone. Or, maybe if you were mutated into half telephone half-human, it would ask about the percentage of the mutation into a telephone (which is probably 30 times more unlikely than the first one).

If you just want to ask someone how many they have, use many and the plural of telephone.

> How many telephones do you have?
>
> I have three telephones.